# Do cars and passenger airplanes use the same type of exterior paint?

Tags: paint

Can you apply a paint used for the exterior of car to the body and wings of a passenger airplane? If no, please explain why? How do the paints used differ?

Comment: This sounds like a question for @JonanthanMusso

Comment: The short answer is yes, but with a whole bunch of important considerations. This would best be asked in a forum about aircraft.

Comment: An airliner encounters much more (and harder) UV light and many temperature cycles from below -50°C to... wherever it lands. This puts much more stress on the paint of an airliner that on that of a car. I guess they have some other paint.

Comment: Did you know there is an [Aviation.SE](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions)?  They would know more about aircraft paint.  Weight and temperature extremes are much more important for a plane, so my gut says automotive paint is not suitable for a plane.

Comment: Please migrate this question there if you feel it's more appropriate in aviation.

Answer (score 2):

Paints that are used for aircraft are different as they need to sustain changing temperature etc. Also it is very thick, usually 12 mm (.5 inch).